# Mathematics textbooks at the college level on Calculus, Linear Algebra, etc. whose copyright has expired

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for Math textbooks whose copyright has expired or have an open source / creative commons compatible copyright.

Topics I'm specifically interested would be those taught to technical majors such as:

1. Calculus
2. Linear Algebra
3. Analysis